# Using a C# list in a Scriptable Object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

had two questions about using lists within a scriptable object in unity, id like to basically add a list that holds answers to a question which are part of an MCQ style project im working on, here is the code i use to create text area within the inspector

```
[SerializeField]
[TextArea(1,2)]
[Range(1,5)]
List<string> answerList = new List<string>();
```

Im able to see the list within the inspector but i run into two issues, the first one is that the 0th element seems to be minimized always, and the second issue is that i'd like the user to only enter 5 possible answers for now but the range attribute seems to be ignored, so im not sure if the range  attribute will work for this case because i am able to create a list in the inspector which is greater than 5.
I've attached an image to show this, any help would be great, thanks guys.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So i did a bit of digging around and managed to find a solution to stopping the list being increased than the max cap size, just used the onvalidate function, still confused at why the 0th element is minimized.